# React can not access JS code from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create list with React, so I am using the module from here https://github.com/pqx/react-ui-tree

I am trying the sample application:
https://github.com/pqx/react-ui-tree/blob/gh-pages/example/app.js

This application renders the following:
React.render(, document.getElementById('app'));

In the same folder, I have an HTML file within which I try to display the tree created by the sample app:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script src="app.js" type="javascript"></script>

<div id="tree">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I open the HTML page in the browser, nothing is rendered.
I don't have much experience with Javascript or React.

Why is this happening?

Do I need to use Gulp or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <script src="app.js" type="javascript"></script>
> ```

The MIME type for JavaScript is `application/javascript` (or the legacy `text/javascript`). Browsers do not recognise the non-standard `javascript` MIME type so will ignore the script.

This error would have been picked up if you had used [the validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Omit the `type` attribute entirely. HTML 5 makes it optional and it defaults to JavaScript.

---

Your next problem is:

> ```
> React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
> ```

You have no element with that ID in your document.

You have one with the id `tree`, but that appears *after* the script, so won't exist at the time you run the script.

Comment: I removed it. Thank you for clarifying. It still doesn't work however.

Comment: I changed that. It still doesn't display but it has progressed. Now it's showing the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` on the first line with an HTML tag in `app.js`.